# SEO analysis report not counting Facebook likes?

Tags: seo, facebook, like, seo-audit

For my website I created a Facebook page. It has 21 likes.

However, the SEO analysis report says the Facebook likes count to zero. How to get the Facebook likes count into the SEO analysis report?

Comment: Which SEO analysis report are you talking about? You need to be careful about results of several SEO tools.

Comment: http://tools.quicksprout.com/analyze/post4city.com  and http://www.similarweb.com/website/post4city.com

Comment: I just think the tools are not up-to-date regarding the likes or your number of likes is too low to be taken into account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party service. Contact their support for assistance.

Comment: It was user error rather than an issue with a 3rd party service @JohnConde

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing likes on the page you set up with URL likes.

Whilst many of these tools don't work correctly, it is in actual fact not the correct answer here. The Quick Sprout tool you're using shows you FB Likes and FB Shares for the URL you're analysing. This has nothing to do with how many likes your FB page has.

As you can see from Facebook's API directly, your URL `post4city.com` has no Facebook shares or likes. http://graph.facebook.com/http://post4city.com

You can also see all URL likes in the top social media channels [here](http://www.likeexplorer.com/?url=http://post4city.com).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But please take a look. https://www.facebook.com/post4city has 21 likes.

Comment: You don't understand - that is for a page you have created on Facebook, those 21 likes have not liked your URL post4city.com, they have liked your Facebook page. They are two completely separate metrics.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I understand the difference. How can I get them to like the URL? Is there anywhere I can get the info? Please help me.

Comment: Yes, you can add the [Facebook Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) to your website and that will like the URL. What most websites do is code it so that it likes the URL of the current page.

Comment: This can can be closed.

Comment: Just mark the answer as correct for the benefit of others visiting this question. It was already closed previously.

Comment: Correct. I understand.